# Distance between two points in 3D - class, methods and objects, TypeError

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, methods

I'm trying to print the distance between two points in 3D using class and methods. I get a `TypeError : distance() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given.`

Here is my code, `k2` and `k3` are the coordinates of the two points.

```
import math
class Point:
def __init__(self, x, y, z):
  self.x = x
  self.y = y
  self.z = z
def __str__(self):
  return "point : ({:d}, {:d}, {:d})".format(self.x,self.y,self.z)
def distance(self):
  distance = sqrt( (x1-x2)**2 + (y1-y2)**2 + (z1 -z2)**2 )
  return distance
k2 = Point(5, 7, 8)
k3 = Point(-3, -2, 5)
print(k3.distance(k2))
```

also tried

```
print(distance(k2, k3))
```

I get a `NameError : name 'distance' is not defined`

please suggest if I am missing something.

Thank you !
*using python 3.7.4  on Mac Terminal*

Comment: Please provide the entire error message, as  well as a [mcve]. The formatting of your code looks broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where do `x1`/`x2`,... come from in the `distance` method? it seems your code wants to conjure them out of thin air...

Also, the method is declared as `def distance(self)`, so it obviously only has a single argument (the reference to the object itself), and does not allow for any additional arguments to be passed to it.

What you really want, is an argument to the `distance` method where you can pass your reference-object to calculate the distance from. *and* you need to use the reference object's and the self object's coordinates to calculate the distance:

```
def distance(self, other):
   d = sqrt( (self.x - other.x)**2 + ...
```

This example is intentionally incomplete, but you should get the idea.
You probably really want to get a read on how to do object-oriented programming in Python (and probably how to do object oriented programming in general)

Comment: Thank you @umlaute, I was able to execute the code.

Comment: if it solved you problem, you should **accept** the answer (that helped you most, in case there are multiple answers). this is important housekeeping, as it helps people to concentrate on unanswered questions rather than spending time with questions that don't need any more attention.